# Encontrar los atributos que tienen cero

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy intentando hacer una función que me indique qué columnas de una df tienen un valor cero.

Por ejemplo:

```
col1=c(10,0,5,9,10,NA)
col2=c(5,3, NA,78,6,34)
col3=c(5,1, NA,48,6,4)
col4=c(1,1, 0,1,6,4)

df1=data.frame(cbind(col1, col2,col4))
```

```
  col1 col2 col4
1   10    5    1
2    0    3    1
3    5   NA    0
4    9   78    1
5   10    6    6
6   NA   34    4
```

```
df2=data.frame(cbind(col2,col3))

  col2 col3
1    5    5
2    3    1
3   NA   NA
4   78   48
5    6    6
6   34    4
```

Función que busca los ceros (MAL HECHA). Es lo que pretendo arreglar.

```
buscar=function(x){
  ifelse(x==0,cat("Hay ceros en",x), cat("No hay ceros") )}
```

Resultado que tendría que salir:

```
buscar(df1)

Hay ceros en col1
Hay ceros en col4
```

```
buscar(df2)
No hay ceros
```

Answer (score 4):

Si te interesa saber si en todo un data.frame hay ceros:

```
any(df1==0)
```

Regresa `TRUE` cuando hay algún cero en el data.frame, `FALSE` cuando no lo hay.

¿Cómo funciona?

- El operador `==` verifica si hay igualdad entre el lado izquierdo y el lado derecho. En el caso de `df1` verifica en cada elemento del data.frame y regresa una matriz lógica de las mismas dimensiones que `df1`.
- `any()` revisa una estructura de datos y regresa `TRUE` si alguno de los elementos es `TRUE`

Para verificar por columnas:

```
sapply(df1, function(x) {
  any(x == 0)
})
```

Es similar al anterior, solo que utiliza `sapply()` para pasar por cada columna del data.frame y regresar el resultado como un vector lógico.